# Solution verification of a periodic orbits existence in a system of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I have the following system of differential equations: $$\begin{cases}f(x,y)=x(1-x-y)\\ g(x,y)=y(1-x-y)\end{cases}$$

I want to see that there are no periodic orbits in the first quadrant. First, note that the lines $x=0$, $y=0$ are two nullclines and the movement is only vertical and horizontal respectively.

Now, taking the Dulac function $\phi(x,y)=\frac{1}{xy}$ I have that $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)\phi(x,y)}{x}+\frac{\partial f(x,y)\phi(x,y)}{y}=\frac{-1}{y}+\frac{-1}{x}<0 \text{ for all }x,y>0$$

Using the Bendixson-Dulac theorem, the system can't have periodic orbits in the first quadrant. The theorem doesn't deny that it could exist a periodic solution that crosses the lines $x=0$,$y=0$, however since the lines $x=0$, $y=0$ are two nullclines it can't happen and therefore we can't have periodic solutions in the first quadrant ($x,y\geq 0$).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Note that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac yx$ is a movement integral so the orbits are  of type $y = \lambda x$ then no closed orbits are possible.

Comment: What I did is incorrect? Isn't what you said an answer and not a hint? If any orbit is of the type $y=\lambda x $ and no closed orbits are possible that is enough, right?

Comment: @codingnight It's another way of concluding that there are no periodic orbits.

Comment: @Casareo So what I did is correct? Just to be completely sure

Comment: What you did is right.